# Save values from form on change via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form and a drop down menu. The drop down menu lists items (1, 2, 3). When you select any of the items, the content gets loaded via ajax. Item 1 (default) is automatically loaded on $(document).ready().

What I am trying to do is to save the values of the form when user changes from an item to an item. For example, item 1 has a description. After user edits the description and changes to item 2, the description of item 1 should be saved to a database. When the user finishes editing item to and goes back to 1, description of item 2 is saved, and description from item 1 is loaded.

The problem I am facing right now is that I am trying to use `$("#myForm").serialize();` to get form values and pass them into save.php page, but since the input is loaded via ajax call, using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    draw_item_meta();
    var vals = $("#myForm").serialize();
}
```

doesnt yield anything while

```
    $("#select_item").on("change", function(){
        save_item_meta(vals);
        draw_item_meta();
    });
```

selects target selected item and adds description from previous item. So if I edit description of item 1 and change to 2, description of item 1 will be saved as description of item 2.

Here's some of the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    draw_item_meta();
    var vals = $("#myForm").serialize();

    $("#select_item").on("change", function(){
        save_item_meta(vals);
        draw_item_meta();
    });
});

function save_item_meta(vals) {

    console.log(vals);
    $.ajax({
        url: "save.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: vals,
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });

    return false; // prevent from submit

}

function draw_item_meta() {
        var ID = $("#select_item").val();
        $.ajax({
           url:"select_item_meta.php",
           type:"POST",
           data: {"ITEMID":ID, "RID":' . $_GET["ID"] . ',},
           success: function(data) {
               $("#lost_meta_box").replaceWith(data)
           }
       });
};

</script>
```

Form is pretty big, so I'll just paste the part I am trying to modify

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="save.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
<textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" name="Desc">' . $r["Desc"] . '</textarea> <!-- $r["Desc"] pulled from db -->
</form>
```

P.S. I removed some php part from the code. Things like `data: {"ITEMID":ID, "RID":' . $_GET["ID"] . ',}` work. My issue is with JS, not PHP or HTML.

Thank you

Edit:

I found a temporary solution of serializing data every n seconds via

```
var vals = null;
setInterval(function(){
    vals = $("#myForm").serialize();
}, 1000); // 1000 = 1 sec
```

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Comment: I didn't get it properly. I think your facing issue with serialize data which is load from Ajax response right?

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava Kind of. The data is loaded from Ajax. If I try to serialize on document.ready then I get nothing as the data is not there?? If I serialize on change, it serializes the new data, not the current one. I hope this clarifies a bit

Comment: You're not getting data on document.ready because response it not there that time.

Comment: Instead of serialize you can use formData as well. Here is [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery](reference link) might be helpful to you

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava thank you. Will have a look